# Disable Google Play Console Integrity API

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api, google-play-core

I recently enabled Google Play Console's Integrity API, but I don't intend on using it, is there a way to disable it?

There doesn't seem to be an option to disable it on Setup > App Integrity > Integrity API
I tried reaching out to the Play Support, but I haven't recieved a response in months.

Comment: Following......

Comment: I'm also following. I first found an answer that said to use adb with the command "adb shell pm disable-feature android.security.play_integrity" (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/231487794/how-to-disable-play-integrity-in-google-play-console?hl=en), but the command isn't recognized in adb when I run it. I also tried without the "-feature" part, but that one gets an error. I'm wondering if there's something special I need to do first.